# Finite difference scheme for hyperbolic system

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, hyperbolic-equations

I'm having a bit of trouble understanding the following, so it'd be great if anyone has any nice explanations! Thanks in advance!

Consider the hyperbolic system $$u_t = Au_x + Bu$$ where $A$ and $B$ are matrices. Why can't we write a stable and convergent finite difference scheme for this PDE if $A$ isn't diagonalizable?

As an aside, I know that, in order for this to be considered a hyperbolic system, $A$ needs to be diagonalizable with real eigenvalues. If $A$ doesn't meet one of those criteria, then the system is called *weakly hyperbolic*.

Answer (score 2):

The system is *weakly hyperbolic* if the matrix $\xi_1 A + \xi_2 B$ has real eigenvalues for all $\xi = (\xi_1, \xi_2)$, but the matrix doesn't need to be diagonalizable. It is known that such systems may be ill-posed (1).
Let us consider a trivial example with $u$ in $\Bbb R^2$, and with the matrices
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix} 1& 1\\ 0& 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and $B = 0$. We have:
$$
\begin{aligned}
{u_1}_t &= {u_1}_x + {u_2}_x \\
{u_2}_t &= {u_2}_x
\end{aligned}
$$
The Cauchy problem could be solved with the method of characteristics. Here, let us apply spatial Fourier transforms instead, which give
\begin{aligned}
{\hat u_1}_t &= \text i k\, ({\hat u_1} + {\hat u_2}) \\
{\hat u_2}_t &= \text i k\, {\hat u_2}
\end{aligned}
in Fourier domain ($\hat u = \int u\, e^{-\text i kx}\text d x$). Integrating these evolution equations, we have
\begin{aligned}
\hat u_1(k,t) &= \big(U_1(k)+ \text i k t\, U_2(k)\big)\, e^{\text i k t}
\\ \hat u_2(k,t) &= U_2(k)\, e^{\text i k t} 
\end{aligned}
where $U_i$ are the spatial Fourier transforms of $u_i$ at $t=0$. Now, the computation of the inverse transforms gives
\begin{aligned}
u_1(x,t) &= u_1(x+t, 0) + t {u_2}_{x}(x+t, 0)\\
u_2(x,t) &= u_2(x+t, 0)
\end{aligned}
which is unbounded as $t$ increases if $u_2$ isn't initially constant. One notes that the Cauchy problem is ill-posed, since an infinitesimal perturbation of the initial data may entail arbitrarily large error at time $t>0$.

---

(1) H.-O. Kreiss, O.E. Ortiz. "Some mathematical and numerical questions connected with first and second order time-dependent systems of partial differential equations." In: J. Frauendiener, H. Friedrich (eds) *The Conformal Structure of Space-Time*, Springer, 2002, p. 359-370. [doi:10.1007/3-540-45818-2_19](https://doi.org/10.1007/3-540-45818-2_19) [arXiv:gr-qc/0106085](https://arxiv.org/pdf/gr-qc/0106085)